# html show this box this radio button selected

Tags: html

this is my first time programming and been trying to solve this problem. Search many placing for answer but still not able to get the result. I'm trying to do is if radio "username" is selected show username and password box and if voucher radio button selected show voucher box. here is the code, now it will show all box. Radio button is not working. Thanks.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="selectLogin" id="password" value="1" onclick = "choiceType()" checked />Username
<input type="radio" name="selectLogin" id="voucher" value="0" onclick = "choiceType()" />Voucher
</form>

function choiceType() {
if (document.getElementById('password').checked) {
    <div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Username:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_user" type="text" class="form-login" title="Username" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>
    <div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Password:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_pass" type="password" class="form-login" title="Password" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>
    } else {
    <div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Voucher:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_voucher" type="text" class="form-login" title="Voucher" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work like PHP; you don't just echo strings into the DOM (most of the time). That's not even syntactically valid - look in your browser's error console and you'll see error messages. Further, it looks like you want to render 2 elements with the same ID, which is _also_ invalid in HTML, since element IDs must be unique. You should be using [DOM API methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM) to control the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div id="voucherId" style="margin-top:20px;">Voucher:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_voucher" type="text" class="form-login" title="Voucher" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>

   <div id="userNameId" style="margin-top:20px;">Username:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_user" type="text" class="form-login" title="Username" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>
   <div id="passwordId" style="margin-top:20px;">Password:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_pass" type="password" class="form-login" title="Password" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>


     function choiceType() {
          var inputs = document.getElementsByName("selectLogin");

           for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].checked) {
                    if( inputs[i].value =="1")
                          {
                             document.getElementById("voucherId").style.display = "block";
                             document.getElementById("userNameId").style.display = "none";
                             document.getElementById("passwordId").style.display = "none";

                          }

                           else  ( inputs[i].value =="0")
                          {
                            document.getElementById("voucherId").style.display = "none";
                            document.getElementById("userNameId").style.display = "block";
                             document.getElementById("passwordId").style.display = "block";
                          }

                      }
                    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:`document.getElementById('you element id').innerHTML`

```
document.getElementById('you element id').innerHTML='<div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Username:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_user" type="text" class="form-login" title="Username" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div><div id="login-box-name" style="margin-top:20px;">Password:</div><div id="login-box-field" style="margin-top:20px;"><input name="auth_pass" type="password" class="form-login" title="Password" value="" size="30" maxlength="2048" /></div>';
```